# Помогите с Fragment

Tags: android-fragment, android, java

Помогите. Нужно в класс, наследованный от **Fragment**, засунуть **ViewPager**:

```
public class PhotoshopFragment extends Fragment{

        private ViewPager mViewPager;
        private PagerTabStrip pagerTabStrip;

        public PhotoshopFragment(){}

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adobephotoshop, container, false);

            mViewPager = (ViewPager) mViewPager.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
            pagerTabStrip = (PagerTabStrip) pagerTabStrip.findViewById(R.id.pagerTabStrip);

            TitleAdapter titleAdapter = new TitleAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            mViewPager.setAdapter(titleAdapter);
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);

            return rootView;

        }
    }
```

Ругается на `getSupportFragmentManager()`.

Поскольку я новичок, не понимаю, как сделать! Ткните пальцем...

Comment: используйте getFragmentManager(). потому что вы вызываете его в фрагменте

Answer (score 1):

Класс Fragment не имеет метода "getSupportFragmentManager()".

Его имеет активити, к которой относится Fragment.

Следовательно в данном случае надо заменить

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
```

на:

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
```

Comment: Насколько мне известно, то `getFragmentManager()` фрагмента вернет то же самое, что и `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()`.

Comment: @Andreich, вполне возможно. Но надо же пояснить человеку, что бывают классы, в которых нет конкретных методов. И что надо немного покопаться в доступных и в структуре архитектуры с фрагментами. =)

Answer (score 0):

Если вызываете во фрагменте, то используйте `getFragmentManager()`.

Comment: Просто TitleAdapter на android.support.v4.app.Fragment; 
а PhotoshopFragment на android.app.Fragment;

Изменить PhotoshopFragment не могу ибо потом начинает материться все!!!

Comment: Плохо, но вам придется привести к одному типу.